# Letting items go off the div in a horizontal list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate this concept app's home page with html css only. Now I want to let the "Top Categories" list go off the outer div just like the one in this picture: (To those concerned, this is not plagiarism, this is a school project of ours.)

[Concept app's front page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrNVH.png):

[image]

[Here's what it looks like right now (added borders for visualization)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDv1u.png):

[image]

I want for the itemlist to be a perfect square for each item (80px by 80px) with the last ones being cut by the div so the user has to scroll to see the end.

```css
html,
body,
* {
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.searcharea {
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.location {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgb(170, 170, 170);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 58px;
}

.searchbar {
  width: 65%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgb(170, 170, 170);
  border: none;
  padding: 0px 57px 0px 13px;
  background-image: url('assets/search-icon.png');
  background-position: 95% 5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.searchbar:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#location_icon {
  font-size: 29px;
}

.categories {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

.categoriesheader {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.items {
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: fit-content;
}

.itemlist {
  position: inherit;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 2px solid black
}

#item1 {
  background-image: url('https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.MfhIfzrC6x6T1-szQkjtCgHaEo?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain');
}

#item2 {
  background-image: url('');
}

#item3 {
  background-image: url('');
}

#item4 {
  background-image: url('');
}

#item5 {
  background-image: url('');
}

#item6 {
  background-image: url('');
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 400, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 24
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
<h1 class="header">FOODIFY</h1>
<div class="searcharea">
  <div class="location">
    <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="location_icon">location_on</span>
  </div>
  <input class="searchbar" placeholder="Search for meals or area"></input>
</div>
<div class="categories">
  <h2 class="categoriesheader">Top Categories</h2>
  <div class="items">
    <ul class="itemlist" id="item1"></ul>
    <ul class="itemlist" id="item2"></ul>
    <ul class="itemlist" id="item3"></ul>
    <ul class="itemlist" id="item4"></ul>
    <ul class="itemlist" id="item5"></ul>
    <ul class="itemlist" id="item6"></ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.items {
    width:100vw;
    display: flex;
    gap: 15px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height: fit-content;
}

.itemlist {
    position: inherit;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 80px;
    min-width: 80px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
   <div class="itemlist" id="item1"></div>
   <div class="itemlist" id="item2"></div>
   <div class="itemlist" id="item3"></div>
   <div class="itemlist" id="item4"></div>
   <div class="itemlist" id="item5"></div>
   <div class="itemlist" id="item6"></div></div>
```

Comment: awesome, one issue tho, I want the horizontal scroll to be in the items or itemslist div, instead, it adds a scroll to the entire document. And what can I do to hide the items' part that is outside the items div?

Comment: @JollyJoe adding `overflow-x: scroll;` to `.items` will make only this div horizontally scrollable not the entire document. You can scroll left to right or right to left to see all the inner divs those are hidden (outside the ".items" width)